# How to get HTML content inside an iFrame to an Action and save it in DB?

Tags: html, ajax, iframe, struts2

I'm having a school timetable manually created. The number of textboxes are 33. I want to store it in db. But what if I store its `innerHtml` content in Db? Since the students can also view the timetable, but fetching that much data may decrease performance. 
I'm trying to get the data using Ajax, but nothing happens. Not even an error. 
I'm working on Java with Struts Framework and the fields are inside an iFrame element. 
I don't know what to write in execute method to get the html content.

Ajax Code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">


        var jarray=[];
        var jsonTT={};
        var jsonTTData="";
        function GenerateTableJson(){
        jsonTTData="";
        jsonTTData=$("#bdyTimeTableData").html();
        jsonTT["timeTable"]=escape(jsonTTData.trim());

        $("#contentTT").val(jsonTT);
        console.log(jsonTT);

        var postdata ={};
        postdata = {
                "FinalSave":[{
                    "timeTable":"TT",
                    "department":$("#departmentid").val(),
                    "semester":$("#semesterid").val(),
                    "division":$("#divisionid").val()
                    }]
        };

        postdata = JSON.stringify(postdata);

        $.ajax({
            url: "SaveNPrintTT.action",
            cache:false,
            contentType : 'application/json',
            type : 'POST',
            async : true,
            data:postdata,
            success:function(res){

                $.ajax({
                    url: url,
                    cache:false,
                    method:"POST",
                    dataType : 'json',
                    success:function(res){

                    }
                }); 


            }
        }); 

        return true;
    }

     function PrintPreview() {
            var toPrint = document.getElementById('bdyTimeTableData');
            var popupWin = window.open('TimeTable', '_blank', 'resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,status=yes');
            popupWin.document.open();
            popupWin.document.write('<html><title>::Print Preview::</title><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Print.css" media="screen"/></head><body onload="window.print()""">')
            popupWin.document.write(toPrint.innerHTML);
            popupWin.document.write('</html>');
            popupWin.document.close();
            window.PrintPreview =PrintPreview;
        }
</script>
```

My JSP code.
Only Textboxes with values.

But for save button, I'm calling Action Class name - saveTT

I need the content in Action to save it in Db. OR Do i write an insert query, inserting 33 values in db?

Comment: Partition the problem... is your problem sending the data? Receiving and saving the data? Presenting a web form, which will collect the data? Each one of those questions is sufficiently complex to warrant it's own question! Please edit the question to reduce scope and if it is sending... what does firebug tell you? At least separate server and client side concerns.

Comment: Are you sending your data to Struts? What do you expect from Struts parsing your data? Saving it into db would be a different question, anyway the technology you use to persist is unknown but it would be a lot of work doing this and better ask it a separate topic.

Comment: Here is what want to do. I have 33 dropdown in JSP. But to save the 33 values in database one by one, I'm thinking of simply saving the html content. Since I also need to show the values to other users, I want that content to be shown on another JSP by simply getting the saved html content from db and display it. How I can do that? Also suggest me what to use, Ajax and then send it to action or a normal action ?